# Why is my rank_sum database column still nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, model

So I have these two methods in my Video model. The first one takes the parameter `store` and does some funky math to it to return `rounded_num`. The second method should be setting `rank_sum` in the database to the value of `rounded_num` by passing the value of `vote_sum` to the `rank_sum` method. Here are the methods:

```
def rank_sum(score)
  order = Math.log10(([score.abs,1].max))

  if score > 0
    sign = 1
  elsif score < 0
    sign = -1
  else
    sign = 0
  end

  seconds = self.created_at - DateTime.new(1970,1,1)
  long_num = order + sign * seconds / 45000
  return rounded_num = (long_num * 10**7).round.to_f / (10**7)
end

def update_rank_sum
  new_rank = rank_sum(self.vote_sum)
  video.update_attributes!(:rank_sum => new_rank)
end
```

However, `rank_sum` is not being set. The value for each video's rank_sum is still nil. How do I fix this?

Comment: How is `update_rank_sum` being called?

Comment: I don't think it is. I assumed it might have been called automatically, but I guess this assumption was faulty. How should I call it? A callback?

Comment: That's what I needed to know :) See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `rank_sum` method doesn't directly interact with an *instance* of the `Video` model (e.g. one specific video) and instead simply does some calculation, I would make it a class method. This also makes it so that your method isn't overwriting Active Record's own `rank_sum` method, which it created based on the columns in your database.

Changing some of the names to be more descriptive and cleaning up the `return` statement in your first method, I would try something like this:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_update :update_rank_sum

  def self.calculate_rank_sum(score, created_at)
    order = Math.log10(([score.abs,1].max))

    if score > 0
      sign = 1
    elsif score < 0
      sign = -1
    else
      sign = 0
    end

    seconds = created_at - DateTime.new(1970,1,1)
    long_num = order + sign * seconds / 45000
    (long_num * 10**7).round.to_f / (10**7)
  end

  def update_rank_sum
    self.rank_sum = Video.calculate_rank_sum(self.vote_sum, self.created_at)
  end
end
```

This will recalculate the `rank_sum` column every time the record is saved. If you only want to recalculate it if a certain field was changed, you can implement that logic in your `update_rank_sum` callback. For example, to only calculate a new `rank_sum` if the `vote_sum` has been changed:

```
def update_rank_sum
  if self.vote_sum_changed?
    self.rank_sum = Video.calculate_rank_sum(self.vote_sum, self.created_at)
  end
  true
end
```

You can replace `vote_sum` in `vote_sum_changed?` with whatever column you want to check.

[Edit] You may need to return a non `false` or `nil` value in the callback to make sure the record still saves (if you return false from a `before_` callback it cancels the save). I've updated the last code block.

Comment: One question. Since this is in the Video model, won't rank_sum only be updated for that video once when the video is created and saved?

Comment: I edited my answer a couple minutes ago from `before_save` to `before_update`, which will update the column every time the model is saved instead of only the first time it's saved. Is this what you want?

Comment: Not quite. What's happening is that the vote_sum, which is passed to `calculate_rank_sum`, is consistently changing whenever a user votes, so I'd want to update rank_sum whenever a user votes. The tricky thing is that voting has its own model, VideoVote.

Comment: Does my latest edit (see near the end) take care of it for ya?

Comment: I think so. This updates the rank_sum if the video is updated with a new vote_sum?

Comment: Yes. In English, "Before saving this video record, check to see if `vote_sum` has been changed. If it has, calculate a new `rank_sum` as well. In either case, proceed with saving the record."

Comment: OK thanks. Any idea what this error is about: NoMethodError (undefined method 'created_at' for #<Class:0x103274918>):
  app/models/video.rb:23:in 'calculate_rank_sum'
  app/models/video.rb:30:in 'update_rank_sum'
  app/models/video_vote.rb:11:in 'update_vote_sum'
  app/controllers/video_votes_controller.rb:22:in 'create'
 It's complaining about `created_at`, but it's an automatic column in the db.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to make sure that the timestamp columns were created. You can check `db/schema.rb`, or on the database console `rails db`, run `select * from sqlite_master where name = 'videos';` (assuming you're using SQLite).

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realized what it was. Since I changed `calculate_rank_sum` to a class method, `self` in that method was `Class`, not an instance of `Video`. I modified the code in my answer to pass in the model's `created_at` attribute in the callback. Sorry about that!

Comment: don't worry about it! Thanks, it works now :) I'd still be at square one if it weren't for you.